# How to programmatically show master view controller on splitViewController when in Portrait orientation?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a UISplitViewController where I need to show the master view controller in both landscape and portrait, currently the user has to either swipe or press a bar button item to show the master view controller but I need it to be visible on page load.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the split view controllers preferredDisplayMode property to UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeSideBySide